# Entity Framework Core How do I query the database in a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to update some data in my database as part of a migration.

The MigrationBuilder has an Update method, which enables me to provide a set of keys and values to update a table. But how do I query the database during the migration in order to determine the keys of the values I need to update?

Comment: what you are looking for is a seeding mechanism i highly recommend to read this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: No it isn't reference data, it's data that has been added to the database during normal operation and which needs to be updated due to the database schema changing.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no migrationBuilder APIs to help with this. (Issue [#5642](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5642#issuecomment-1291884446) was closed as out of scope.) You have to use the `Sql` method to write your own logic.

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    UPDATE Employees
    SET Salary = Salary * 1.06
    WHERE Level > 5;
");
```